# How to get data from JSON string

Tags: c#, json, facebook, class, facebook-graph-api

A bit explanation. I was using Facebook API to integrate with my C# application. Since Facebook has updated the API. I have the problem to keep JSON result that returned by Facebook to be use in my code. Previously the result that return by Facebook in JSON object. I knew how to desirelized JSON object.

Problem now is JSON return as a string. What can i do to catch the data from the JSON string?

This is the JSON that given by Facebook

```
{"id":"t_mid.1468318160994:4fbaede7284fc37853","messages":{"data":[{"created_time":"2016-07-12T10:09:21+0000","id":"m_mid.1468318160994:4fbaede7284fc37853"}],"paging":{"previous":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/t_mid.1468318160994:4fbaede7284fc37853/messages?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]&limit=25&since=1468318161&__paging_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]&__previous=1","next":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/t_mid.1468318160994:4fbaede7284fc37853/messages?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]&limit=25&until=1468318161&__paging_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]"}}}
    base {System.Dynamic.DynamicObject}: {"id":"t_mid.1468318160994:4fbaede7284fc37853","messages":{"data":[{"created_time":"2016-07-12T10:09:21+0000","id":"m_mid.1468318160994:4fbaede7284fc37853"}],"paging":{"previous":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/t_mid.1468318160994:4fbaede7284fc37853/messages?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]&__previous=1","next":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/t_mid.1468318160994:4fbaede7284fc37853/messages?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]&limit=25&until=1468318161&__paging_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]"}}}
    Count: 2
    IsReadOnly: false
    Keys: Count = 2
    Values: Count = 2
```

This is my code to getting the data from the string

```
public class GetMesaggeIDUsingConversationID_API_V2_6
{
    public messages id { get; set; }
    public class messages
    {
        public Data[] data { get; set; }
        public class Data
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
    }
}

List<GetMesaggeIDUsingConversationID_API_V2_6> msgApiforGetMsgID = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetMesaggeIDUsingConversationID_API_V2_6>>("JSON STRING HERE");
```

But its become error.

The error is :

```
"Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Collections.Generic.List<Orlig_Server_Services.Components.Refer.GetMesaggeIDUsingConversationID_API_V2_6>>(string)' has some invalid arguments\r\n   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )\r\n   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)\r\n   at Orlig_Server_Services.Components.FacebookIntegration.getFanMessage() in D:\\Projects\\Orlig_FB_Service V3.2 API V2.6\\Components\\FacebookIntegration.cs:line 2874"
```

Please give me some suggestion. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: your facebook api json seems to be invalid. i checked it and the format result seems to be incorrect. its not even an array, so you may want to do some decoupling of the response before deserializing it with Json.Net

look here: http://clip2net.com/s/3APtRnE

Answer (score 0):

Your string's are in JSON format. You want to parse them, so you need to use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).

```
string source = "JSON..."
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(source);

Console.WriteLine(data.id);
Console.WriteLine(data.messages);
// ...
```